# Add Form lock out time limit

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

using PHP or with Javascript how can i create a timeout to prevent logins from being rapidly submitted?

I validate the log in form using PHP, connects with DB, and then returns true or false whether the log in is valid and such. On an invalid log in, I am thinking of setting a cookie for login-timeout that increments in N amount after M amounts of failed login attempts.

Would a cookie be the best way? What if the user does not enable cookies, much like i do? Sessions get unset at the beginning of the log in page, so I cannot set a trusted $_SESSION value, plus the user can just leave the site and come back.

Is a cookie the best way?

Comment: A $_SESSION variable would be the better choise, if the user got no session then he needs to get one first. After he got one he can request a login. Then you can store the last login attempt in the session and you can calculate when teh user can login again.

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit Most bruteforce bots dont maintain cookies so session wont help. I would increment a value in the db on failed attempts and when > 10 limit the response time, so bruteforcing is simply not economical, they will soon notice an give up if it takes 60 seconds to try 60 passwords. A legit user won't notice a 1 second delay.

Comment: If you Check If the User got a Session before validating his Login Data then its Work Like a charm

Comment: How would you do that? As session_start() would just create a new session each time, so the bot would always have a session.

Comment: Just put it into the form.  You didn't mention if the user could defeat this by editing the data.

Comment: Then teh bots need to request two times for one request, that at least a solution. you can also create a ip blocking script which takes the ip from the user which tries to login and puts it into a temp table where you look first before you try to login to see if the given user has tried it from teh same ip multiple times allready.